# Shuffle Cards. segmentation fault if I try to print a char composed of pointers

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, pointers, random

I have this code that randomizes cards. I know that it is not complete, since if `rand()` chooses a FACE or a SUIT already chosen, everything will not have any sense, so I still don't know how can I fix that part.

Anyway, the current problem is that after I compile and run this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define FACES 4
#define SUITS 4

void shuffle(const char *sFace[], const char *sSuits[], char cards[FACES][SUITS]);

int main(){
    const char *face[FACES] = {"Jack", "Queen", "King", "Ace"};
    const char *suit[SUITS] = {"Hearts", "Spades", "Diamonds", "Clubs"};
    char cards[FACES][SUITS] = {0};         // initialize the cards array

    shuffle(face, suit, cards);
}

void shuffle(const char *sFace[], const char *sSuits[], char cards[][SUITS]){
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (size_t i=1; i<=FACES; ++i){
        const size_t fac = rand() % FACES;
        for (size_t j=1; j<=SUITS; ++j){
            const size_t sui = rand() % SUITS;
            cards[fac][sui] = ("%s of %s", **(sFace+fac), **(sSuits+sui));  // save the card string
            printf("%s", cards[fac][sui]);  // print the card string
        }
    }
}
```

it gives me a `Segmentation Fault: 11`.

I know that I must have done something wrong with cards[fac][sui] memorization.

**EDIT**:

New code with sprintf and with increased dimension of the multi dim array, still get Segmentation Fault:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define FACES 4
#define SUITS 4

void shuffle(const char *sFace[], const char *sSuits[], char cards[FACES*SUITS][20]);

int main(){
    const char *face[FACES] = {"Jack", "Queen", "King", "Ace"};
    const char *suit[SUITS] = {"Hearts", "Spades", "Diamonds", "Clubs"};
    char cards[FACES*SUITS][20] = {0};          // initialize the cards array

    shuffle(face, suit, cards);
}

void shuffle(const char *sFace[], const char *sSuits[], char cards[FACES*SUITS][20]){
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (size_t i=1; i<=FACES; ++i){
        const size_t fac = rand() % FACES;
        for (size_t j=1; j<=SUITS; ++j){
            const size_t sui = rand() % SUITS;
            sprintf(cards[fac][sui], "%s of %s\n", *(sFace+fac), *(sSuits+sui));  // save the card string
            printf("%s", cards[fac][sui]);   // print card string
        }
    }
}
```

I think I still get Segmentation Fault because I am using a two dimension array. In a one dimension array it works. So what can I do to save that string inside my multi dimension array?

Comment: Please look up the [Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, `char cards[FACES][SUITS]` with `#define SUITS 4` only has space for 4 characters to each line, it is not possible to store the text `"Queen of Diamonds"` in it, so I suggest using something like `char cards[FACES*SUITS][20]` instead. (Changing the parameters of the `shuffle` function accordingly)

Then, using specifiers like `("%s of %s", **(sFace+i), **(sSuits+sui))` is a behavior specific to the functions of the `printf`-family functions, and definitely won't work by itself. What you want is to use the function `sprintf` that allows you to store the formatted string in an array of chars, instead of printing it as the `printf` function would do.

Example:

```
char array[12];
sprintf(array, "%s %s", "Hello", "World");
printf(array); // prints "Hello World"
```

Finally, the best way to generate a shuffled/randomized list of elements (in your case a deck of cards) without duplicated elements, is to first create the list with all the unique elements (not shuffled yet), and then use the Fisher-Yates shuffle algorithm to shuffle the list.

**EDIT:**

To answer your comment bellow you would do something like this:

```
void shuffle(const char *sFace[], const char *sSuits[], char cards[FACES*SUITS][20]){
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (size_t i=0; i<FACES; ++i){
        for (size_t j=0; j<SUITS; ++j){
            sprintf(cards[i*SUITS+j], "%s of %s\n", *(sFace+i), *(sSuits+j));  // save the card string
            printf("%s", cards[i*SUITS+j]);   // print card string
        }
    }

    /*Add Fisher-Yates shuffle here*/

}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. You made some things clearer to me. I tried to use sprintf in my code, but still get segmentation error. It's because I am using a two dimension array. In a one dimension array it works. So what can I do to save that string inside my multi dimension array? I also put char cards[FACES*SUITS][20] as you suggested. I have put the code in the thread.

Answer (score 1):

`printf("%s", cards[fac][sui]);`

`cards[fac][sui]` is a `char` not the `char *`. So you try to print the integer value of the `char` converted to `char *`. It is an ***Undefined Behaviour*** of course and in your case it ends up in the Segfaault.

On the other hand the 
`cards[fac][sui] = ("%s of %s", **(sFace+fac), **(sSuits+sui));` does not make any sense. It converts the reference to the string literal "%s of %s" to `char` and stores it in the array.

You have a bunch of warnings when compile this code. **Always** read the warnings. Never ignore them.

You need to learn pointers, arrays and some another basics.

Answer (score 0):

`cards[fac][sui] = ("%s of %s", **(sFace+fac), **(sSuits+sui));` line is bad. Your declaration is `char cards[FACES][SUITS]` which will store only a character but you are trying to assign `%s of %s` which won't work because it is string and anyway you do not assign strings like that but rather do something like `strcpy` or `sprintf` which is more useful in your case.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I have put a new updated code using sprintf, but I still get Segmenation Fault.